# How to compute the 2020th homotopy group of $S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose the world would end if we don't know $\pi_{2020}(S^2)$ by the end of 2020.

**What shall we do to compute $\pi_{2020}(S^2)$ by whatever means?**

Comment: Find a bunch of algebraic topologists and lock them in a room?

Comment: @Math1000 Good idea, but maybe not practical.

Comment: This thread is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31004/computational-complexity-of-computing-homotopy-groups-of-spheres

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks for the link. Not sure if the program Kenzo is capable to compute this far though. We also have to make sure the computer has enough memory. Another issue is how much do we trust computers?

Comment: I'd reduce the problem to computing $\pi_{2020}(S^3)$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Care to explain more?

Comment: It’s a joke. The homotopy groups of $S^3$ are those of $S^2$ above $2$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin So you jump to a higher sphere along a long exact sequence.

Comment: Yes, it comes from the LES for the Hopf fibration. It is unique to this fibration because the higher homotopy groups of the circle vanish. For other sphere fibrations, you basically are getting an approximation that depends on the higher homotopy groups of the sphere that is the fiber.